# Code 128C Barcode giving X dimension a decimal value does not scan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, barcode

Generated a Code128C barcode as follows,

```
def get_barcode_img(string, xdim)
    binary_barcode = Barby::Code128C.new(string)
    outputter = Barby::RmagickOutputter.new(binary_barcode)
    outputter.height, outputter.xdim = 96, xdim
    encoded_image = Base64.encode64(outputter.to_jpg.to_s).gsub(/\s+/, "") 
end
```

in view file

```
<% barcode = get_barcode_img("123456", 1.44)  %>
<%= image_tag("data:image/jpg;base64,#{Rack::Utils.escape(barcode)}") %>
```

the barcode thus generated is a bit blurry, which I think is a reason for the barcode cant be scanned.

[image: code 128C barcodes with different xdims]

Its clearly visible that the barcode with xdim = 1.44 (in pixels) is alone blurry and also the same cant be scanned with a android barcode scanner app while other two barcodes are easily scanned.

I tried to print barcodes with other barby outputters like HtmlOutputter, PDFWriterOutputter and PrawnOutputter but in vain.

Would desperately like to know if there is anyway to provider the xdim in decimal and get the desired result?

Thank you.